# html link import не работает в Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

есть такой код (файл index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function show() {
    var time = link.import.querySelector('*');
    document.body.appendChild(time);
};
</script>
<link rel="import" id="link" onload="show()" href="timer.html">
</body>
</html>
```

и файл timer.html:

```
<h2>Some test from "timer" file</h2>
```

в общем не работает импорт файла timer.html в index.html в Firefox 44.0.2, а в Opera и Chrome все работает нормально. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным и знает как разрешить ситуацию и заставить код работать?

Answer (score 3):

Вот и я столкнулся с той же проблемой . А причина проста в FireFox поддержка HTML Imports отключена . ссыль https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/HTML_Imports